# Defining the dot product between two curls in higher dimensions

Tags: vector-analysis

I'm trying to find $(\nabla \times \vec{A}) \cdot (\nabla \times \vec{A})$, when $\vec{A}$ is defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $n>3$.

The answer for $n=3$ is already in the forum but, I'm not sure the curl is defined for all $n$, and I was hoping to side step that issue by finding an expression that will give me a sensible (though, evidently, not mathematically accurate) result even when the curl may not be defined.

Comment: In R3, curl actually refers to the plane in which the vector field is curling, so the correct representation of it is as a bivector, which is a plane with magnitude and direction, instead of a vector's line with magnitude and direction. Fortunately, in 3 dimensions we can represent any bivector as a vector whose line is perpendicular to the original's plane. Unfortunately, this is not possible in higher dimensions.

Comment: Just to supplement @TomKern's pouring of cold water, in $n$ dimensions the Levi-Civita symbol has $n$ indices, so $\nabla\times\vec{A}$ has $n-2$. For $n\ge4$, this affords us multiple ways to contract all these indices with those in another copy of $\nabla\times\vec{A}$ to form a scalar, no one of which should obviously be called the dot product (although contracting the $k$th index in one with the $k$th in the other is one natural interpretation in a vector space of dimension $n^{n-2}$).

Answer (score 0):

There's a notion of inner product of $k$-forms given by

$$
g_{(k)}(\omega,\eta)
=
\frac{1}{k!}
g^{a_1b_1}\cdots g^{a_kb_k}
\omega_{a_1\dots a_k}
\eta_{b_1\dots b_k}
$$

(see e.g. chapter 0 of Gauge theory and variational principles, by David Bleecker).

So you can generalize the idea of "the squared norm of ghe curl" using the norm induced by this inner product:
$$
\|\omega\|^2
=
\frac{1}{k!}
g^{a_1b_1}\cdots g^{a_kb_k}
\omega_{a_1\dots a_k}
\omega_{b_1\dots b_k}
$$

Now the form you will be taking the norm of should be the Hodge dual of the exterior derivative of the $n-1$ form $A$ corresponding to $\vec A$. Using Bleecker's normalizations (which are pretty standard) this is

$$
(dA)_{ab} = 2\nabla_{[a}A_{b]}
$$

$$
(\star dA)_{a_1\dots a_{n-2}} =
\frac{2}{2!}
g^{ac}g^{bd}
\nabla_{[a}A_{b]}
E_{cda_1\dots a_{n-2}}
=
g^{ac}g^{bd}
\nabla_{[a}A_{b]}
E_{cda_1\dots a_{n-2}}
$$
where $E_{cda_1\dots a_{n-2}}$ is the Levi-Civita tensor.
Now applying $g_{(n-2)}$

$$
\begin{align}
\|\star dA\|^2
&=
\frac{1}{(n-2)!} g^{ac}g^{bd}
\nabla_{[a}A_{b]}
E_{cda_1\dots a_{n-2}}
\nabla_{[u}A_{v]}
E^{uva_1\dots a_{n-2}} \\
&=
\frac{1}{(n-2)!} g^{ac}g^{bd}
\nabla_{[a}A_{b]}
\nabla_{[u}A_{v]}
\delta_{cda_1\dots a_{n-2}}^{uva_1\dots a_{n-2}} \\
&=
g^{ac}g^{bd}
\nabla_{[a}A_{b]}
\nabla_{[u}A_{v]}
\delta_{cd}^{uv} \\
&=
4 g^{ac}g^{bd}
\nabla_{[a}A_{b]}
\nabla_{[c}A_{d]}.
\end{align}
$$
For $n=3$ this reduces to the usual squared norm of the curl:
$$
\|\nabla\times\vec A\|^2
=
4 g^{ac}g^{bd}
\nabla_{[a}A_{b]}
\nabla_{[c}A_{d]}.
$$